# Como Exploits são criados?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exploit

Estava pesquisando sobre segurança em servidores, e esbarrei no assunto de exploits, já entendi a lógica de um ataque DDOS e um exploit buffer overflow, mas estou curioso para uma coisa:

Como os hackers criam um exploit? Tipo que métodos podem ser usados para analisar um servidor por fora, e que testes são feitos até a confirmação de que ele funciona?

Quais são as informações que eles usam para programar por exemplo usando `socket` ou sei la o que?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quer se tornar um Hacker ? lol

Para se criar um exploit é preciso encontrar alguma vulnerabilidade, a brecha será usada para criar métodos que se aproveite da falha encontrada!

Em linux geralmente tudo é OpenSource, então as falhas são encontradas ao analisar os códigos, é claro que para encontrar Bugs você tem que entender como determinado método ou pedaço de código funciona (se você entender a lógica, existe chance de vc imaginar como sabotar lol lol), imagine que eu comesse analisar os códigos do `apache` e que em algum local dentro do código encontre uma variável definindo um tamanho fixo de buffer para envio dentro de um socket, então o que aconteceria se eu conseguisse enviar mais dados que o socket pode ler ? será que iria causar um `BufferOverflow` ? se isso causar estouro de pilha na memória será que consigo escrever um `shell code` que aponte para o endereço de retorno na memória e execute um código malicioso ? é assim que funciona, você simplesmente tem que encontrar e aplicar possíveis situações que não estão sendo tratadas no código, então se isso for um bug explorável irá conseguir replicar o exploit para ser usado em todas as versões de `apache` na qual você encontrou a falha, claro se o bug for reportado a próxima versão virá com um "remendo" fechando a falha huahuahua!

Mais ai vc me pergunta e o windows não temos os códigos para olhar, hahaha tem muito código do kernel do windows que vazou na década 2000, muitas vulnerabilidades foram descobertas analisando esses pedaços de códigos, é claro que alguns bugs podem ser descobertos na força bruta, apenas tentando imaginar como algo funciona, além disso quando alguém quer ir a fundo mesmo acaba efetuando engenharia reversa para entender como a lógica funciona, entendendo a lógica você pode imaginar maneiras de causar falhas e sabotar ...

Vale lembrar que os sistemas operacionais passaram por muitos problemas de segurança no início, hoje em dia eles estão muito maduros, eu adorava o `windows95`, ele parecia um queijo suíço hahaha

Comment: Então o método que você está falando para encontrar falhas e na base da tentativa e erro?

Comment: ler os códigos se eles forem opensource, se não forem opensource vc pode aplicar engenharia reversa, por ultimo saber mais ou menos como algo funciona e tentar na base da tentativa e erro ...

Comment: Como eu faço engenharia reversa?